# CSS accordion pictures don't show on WordPress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, accordion

I'm sure I am just missing something simple but it is eluding me.  I am trying to get a CSS accordion to work and have each section link to a page.

Here is the source http://www.webarti.com/css3-horizontal-accordion-slider/content-slider/

Here is my current test site:  http://g6t.test-lca-website.com/

I have the accordion part working (with only one odd quirk, the first bar disappears when you move to the second bar, but that can be dealt with a little later) but the pictures will not show at all.  Right now I only have one picture assigned to the "Payment Processing" slider that is not showing.

This is my code:

```
<!-- CSS3 Accordion -->
    <div class="accordion">
    <!--[if IE ]><ul class="accordion-ie"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>--><ul><!--<![endif]-->
            <li>    
                <a href="##"><span>Payment Processing </span></a>
                <div>
                <img border="0" alt="" src="img/blank-card-bills.jpg">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="##"><span>Prepaid VISA/Mastercard cards </span></a>
                <div>
                <
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="##"><span>Banking Software </span></a>
                <div>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="##"><span>FX Trading </span></a>
                <div>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="##"><span>Equities Trading</span></a>
                <div>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="##"><span>CFD Trading</span></a>
                <div>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--CSS3 Accordion -->
```

I have a folder in the root of the site called `img` with 755 permissions set.  I have tried even putting this folder in the `wp-content/` folder just to see if that made any difference.  It did not.

I have tried just using an image that is working just fine (i.e. the Logo) and it will not load up the logo in the slider.  With the Logo, I used the full URL with http (as it is currently used).

Update:  The image used is readily available by the it's URL (I can't put more than 2 links here till I get to 10 rep, but just take the base site URL add in /img/blank-card-bills.jpg)

Any/all suggestion are welcomed and appreciated!

Forgot to include the CSS:

```
/*  CSS3 Horizontal Accordion Slider / Video Gallery Version: 1.0
Author: Webarti
Author URL: http://www.webarti.com/
*/
/*********** Global Styles ***********/
body {
background-color:#1a77b8;
color:#1E1C21;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:13px;
padding:0 0 15px 0;
margin:0;
}

.container {
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
background-color:#111111;
border:1px solid #2c2c2c;
margin:90px auto 25px auto;
padding:30px;
width:830px;
}

.header {
color:#666;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:30px;
font-style:italic;
height:65px;
letter-spacing:-1px;
margin:0 0 0 -20px;
padding:25px 0 0 8px;
position:absolute;
text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000000;
top:7px;
width:900px;
word-spacing:5px;
}

/*********** Theme Styles ***********/
.accordion  {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.accordion>ul>li>a {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
box-shadow:inset 1px 0px 0px 0px #485CBD;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#320BB8',  endColorstr='#320078');
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.05, #320BB8), color-stop(1, #320078) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( right center, #320BB8 5%, #320078 100% );
background-color:#320BB8;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#321D85;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:-1px -1px 0px #3227B0;
}

.accordion>ul>li>a:hover{
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#320078',  endColorstr='#320BB8');
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #320078), color-stop(1, #320BB8) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( top center, #320078 5%, #320BB8 100% );
background-color:#9B0629;
}

.accordion>ul>li>div {
background-color:#000000;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

/******** Theme Structure *********/
.accordion>ul>li>div {
height:304px;
padding:10px;
width:600px;
}

.accordion>ul>li>a {
border-width:0 1px 0 0;
width:40px;
}

ul.accordion-ie>li>a>span { /* IE only */
margin-left:10px;
/* This value is  necessary for centering rotated texts in Internet Explorer. */
}

.accordion  {   
width:825px;
/*  This value refers to the total width of visible components
    width = accordion>ul>li>div ( width + paddingRight + paddingLeft )  
        + accordion>ul>li>a ( number of accordions x ( width + borderRrightWidth ) )  
    width = ( 600px + 10px + 10px ) + ( 5 x ( 40px +1px ) )
    width = 825px
*/
}

.accordion, .accordion>ul>li>a  {   
height:324px;
/*  This value refers to the total height of visible area
    height = accordion>ul>li>div ( height + paddingTop + paddingBottom  ) 
    width = ( 304px + 10px + 10px )
    width = 324px
*/
}
.accordion>ul>li {
margin-right:-620px; 
/*  This value refers to the negative of total width of content <div>
    margin-right = accordion>ul>li>div (width + padding-right + padding-left)
    margin-right = 600px + 10px + 10px 
    margin-right = 620px
*/

width:661px;
/*  width = .accordion>ul>li>div ( width + padding-right + padding-left ) 
            + .accordion>ul>li>a ( width + border-right )
    width = ( 600px + 10px + 10px ) + ( 40px + 1px )
    width = 661px
*/

   /* Transition Effect */
transition: margin-right 0.3s ease 0.2s;
-moz-transition: margin-right 0.3s ease 0.2s;
-webkit-transition: margin-right 0.3s ease 0.2s;
-o-transition: margin-right 0.3s ease 0.2s;
}


/*******  Do not change folllowing properties  **********/
.accordion  {overflow:hidden;}
.accordion>ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;width:9999em;}
.accordion>ul>li {float:left;overflow:hidden;}
.accordion>ul>li>a {float:left;position:relative;z-index:1;-moz-outline-style:none;outline:none;}
.accordion>ul>li>a>span{ /* Text Rotation for all browsers */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -ms-writing-mode:lr-bt;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
bottom:20px;display:block;position:absolute;width:100%;white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.accordion-ie >li>a>span {cursor:pointer;width:auto;} /* IE only */
.accordion>ul>li>div {float:left;overflow:auto;}
.accordion>ul>li:hover {margin-right:0px;}
ul.accordion-ie>li:hover {margin-right:0px;} /* IE only */
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing the `display` property to none and then using `onClick` in JavaScript to change the property to `display:block` afterwards like so:

```
<div id="accordianDiv" onClick = "appear"></div>
```

And then

```
function appear() {
    div = document.getElementById("accordianDiv");
    div.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.  That and getting into JavaScript still kinda confuses me a bit.  Working on understanding JS better.

Comment: @DragonDon Ok, I totally understand, JS is very confusing at first! I think that may be the only way around this though...

Comment: So can you explain to me why the code you suggest will make a difference?  I did a jquery course on codecademy and went through showing/hiding things/menus but what I'm not making the connection on is how does that make the image associated with this setup appear?  Or are you saying scrap the CSS code altogether?  Then I'm back to "Where the heck does this code even go?" question I always run into when I see answers.

Comment: @DragonDon Yeah, that would be a problem and maybe a bit harder with JS, I have taken the course on Codecademy as well :) I would try changing some of the position attributes to make the images appear though.

Comment: I decided to find another CSS solution and this one works great.  I've combined some elements from the original one and now it's looking good :)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that worked better without any image hassles.  I've also combined some of the styling elements and everything works great.

This site has a great solution for this problem:  http://designshack.net/articles/css/build-a-freaking-awesome-pure-css-accordion/